# Sending text to a Terminal or iTerm2 window?

Tags: terminal, automation

How can I send text to a Terminal or iTerm window?

I'm presenting a demo of some multi-user software and would like to create several windows, programatically sending (different) text to each one, something like

```
send to terminal window 1:  insert into foo values('hello');
send to terminal window 2:  insert into foo values('world');
etc...
```

I'm currently using Terminal and iTerm, but can use any other program.

Comment: From where (which application) do you want to send the text? Do you want to just display the text or do you want to have it handles as if a user typed it?

Comment: As if a user typed it.  Context:  imagine a demo with the narration "user 1 adds record foo in window 1, user 2 adds bar in window 2."  I'm guessing there's applescript involved, so I'm open to any program (even a shell script with osascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Applescript keystroke command.

```
tell application "iTerm" to activate
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "abc"
    keystroke space
    delay 0.2    
    keystroke "c" using control down
end tell
```